# I can't create Password edittext programmatically?

Tags: android

`setInputType()` and `setTransformationMethod()` is not working while I creating Password EditText programmatically in android...

My Code :

```
EditText edtPassword = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
edtPassword.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

This is not working...

Comment: what does "is not working" mean

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: do you even need the setInputType and setTransformationMethod?

Comment: my password is still visible while entering in EditText

Comment: `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` comes first. check your code carefully

Comment: Still not working, entered password is visible

Answer (score 2):

you havent add the edittext in view ,so it may not working ... 
This code worked fine for me

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);


            EditText lEditText = new EditText(this);
            lEditText .setLayoutParams(new           LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             lEditText.setText("Text Here");
             mLinearLayout.addView(lEditText);
             lEditText.setWidth(50);     // change width
             lEditText.setHeight(20); 

             lEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Without setting the transformation. Or if it does not work the setinput method, use the setTransformation but not the both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have try your code in both ways but it is not working. setInputType() or setTransformationMethod() is not working.

Comment: What is the result ? Just some normal text input ?
Did you put TYPE_CLASS_TEXT first ?

Comment: why don't you make the edittext from the xml file ? from there it should work for sure

Answer (score 0):

change

```
edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

to

```
editPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

For password style implementation, for the editText, the code is,

```
editPassword.setTransformationMethod
(new android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod().getInstance());
```

The `setTransformationMethod` function transforms the input value to a (dot) after some interval or after input of next character before the interval is completed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
EditText edtPassword = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
edtPassword.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the TextView docs, the programmatic version of android:password is `setTransformationMethod()`. So something like:

`mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());` should do the work.

If it doesn't work try this

```
Password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: What if both don't work? For me it works in the emulators but not on actual devices :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in `onCreate()` method where you created the edittext

```
edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

After that create the `PasswordTransformationMethod` class in the same activity:

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; 
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; 
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); 
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); 
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

password is not hiding by default that's why i applied

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        this.edtv.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
    },100)
```

this will work for me